# Find post tags words in post content and link them to tag URLs

Tags: posts, search, tags, the-content

I would like to create link of word(s) in post content (word(s) which is used as post tag of current post) to post tag URL.
I created this, and it works, but only for one word (last tag) of post.

```
$post_content = get_the_content(); // Get post content
$search = array($tag->name);
$replace = array('<a href="'.get_tag_link($tag->term_id).'" title="'.$tag->name.'" itemprop="url">'.$tag->name.'</a>');
$replacePairs = array_combine($search, $replace);
echo strtr($post_content, $replacePairs);
```

How to make it search for all words of tags (of current post) in post content and link that words to it's tag URLs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use power of PHP. [Explode the Words](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [Implode them](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).
After exploding it you will get an array, with which you can loop through using [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and call your function conditionally.

Comment: Could yoy please write that php code, to se it? Thanks.

Comment: @AdvancedSEO  Please see the manual [string replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and replace the matching tags with the warpped url you want to replace.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please provide complete function in working mode. I have also same requirement but not working. here is the code.

````
<?php

function save_post_content_with_hyperlinks( $post_id, $post_content ) {

    // Check if the user is an admin.
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Check if the post ID is null.
    if ( is_null( $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Check if the post content is null.
    if ( is_null( $post_content ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Get the post tags.
    $post_tags = get_the_tags( $post_id );

    // Check if the post tags are null.
    if ( is_null( $post_tags ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Create an array of hyperlinked tag keywords.
    $hyperlinked_tags = array();
    foreach ( $post_tags as $tag ) {

        // Check if the tag is null.
        if ( is_null( $tag ) ) {
            continue;
        }
    
        $hyperlinked_tag = null;
        if ( ! is_null( $tag ) ) {
            $hyperlinked_tag = '<a href="' . get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) . '">' . $tag->name . '</a>';
        }
        $hyperlinked_tags[] = $hyperlinked_tag;
    }

    // Replace the tag keywords with hyperlinked tag keywords in the post content.
    $post_content = str_replace( $post_tags, $hyperlinked_tags, $post_content );

    // Update the post content in the database.
    wp_update_post( array(
        'ID'           => $post_id,
        'post_content' => $post_content,
    ) );

    // Return the post content with hyperlinks.
    return $post_content;

}
add_filter( 'save_post', 'create_hyperlinks_for_tag_keywords', 10, 2 );```
````